# How to only handle the last created out of many parallel promises?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, parallel-processing, promise

I am developing a web application in JavaScript that allows for filtering a list. For better UX we do not prevent changing the selected filter option while the list is being refreshed. Problem is that if the filter is changed rapidly multiple times the resulting list may not match the last created promise, because an earlier promise may have resolved last.

I have considering cancelling previous requests but I think allowing the requests to be completed and cached in the background can be a good thing.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a function for getting the response. Could you send back the search string also and check if it matches the string from the filter option? Also I think you might consider using a timeout before searching. This might help with your problem, but it should also make your code work faster if the filter changes a lot in a short period. So put like a 0.2 or 0.5 sec timeout before sending the request and if the filter changes cancel the previous timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually solve this sort of problem by having something I can refer to to find out whether a response coming in is stale or not. Here's an example using `setTimeout` to emulate ajax:

```js
function ajax(request) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                request,
                response: "Response for " + request
            });
        }, Math.random() * 5000);
    });
}

let currentRequest = null;
function doRequest(request) {
    currentRequest = request;
    ajax(request)
    .then(({request, response}) => {
        if (request === currentRequest) {
            console.log("Current response: " + response);
        } else {
            console.log("Ignored stale response: " + response);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}

for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    doRequest(String(n));
}
```

In that example, `currentRequest` keeps track of which is the most recent request. Responses that don't match it are ignored (well, displayed, but we say they're ignored).